# SQL substring starting at x character

Tags: sql, substring

Is there a way to use substring in SQL that extracts to letters after the first two letters from the left?

For example for the word Apple    the substring should extract pl     or for word Exchange, ch would be extracted.

Comment: Please add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality varies between them. (This is suggested in the tag wiki for the SQL tag you added, if you had read that description when adding it.)

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT SUBSTRING('Apple', 3, 2);`

SUBSTRING(string, start, length)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL
Syntax:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING("String", starting position, no of characters) 
SELECT SUBSTRING("Apple", 3, 2) ;
```

Result

```
pl
```